# Is it possible to add music to your Music Library on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music, mp3

Possible use cases. Someone emails you a music demo. You find a song you want to download online. You want to download an MP3 from Soundcloud.

It is easy to add songs to iTunes and sync it over with a computer, but is it possible to add songs to your Music Library on your actual phone? i

Comment: This blows me away. It's my device, it's my file, but Apple thinks they know better about how I "should" want to access it. And of course that way is the wretched iTunes app. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently impossible. You can share downloaded audio with many apps - Dropbox, Google Drive, or the one I use most often for learning music and the like, forScore. But you can't share it with iTunes. Although, songs purchased on your phone can easily (or automatically) added to the libraries of your other Apple devices via Settings - iTunes & App Store and selecting Music under Automatic Downloads.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download the file from your email to Mac(book). Then open iTunes (login with Apple ID if required). Then add downloaded file into iTunes library and sync with your iPhone. It worked for me. Hope this will help.

Comment: You need to download the file that your received to your computer. Somewhere you can easily locate it. Then you need to download iTunes on your Mac or laptop if you already haven't done so. Use your charging wire and connect your iPhone to your computer. Login into your Apple ID on iTunes. Drag and drop your file that you saved earlier to iTunes. Drag that file to your iPhone. And into your playlists if desired. PS: I don't download my music though iTunes. I use this method to get free music without paying anything. Hope this helped @Joshua Dance

Comment: Makes sense, but in the question I mention 'on the iPhone'. It is easy to load songs on the the iPhone with a computer, I want to do it without a computer. Sorry if that was not clear. I can edit the question.